# Assign different color palettes for different category groups in a same seaborn barplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, palette

I am trying to plot a bar graph using sns.barplot for my category groups. Each group has several different items (each > 5). I want to set different color palettes for different groups. Something similar to [Distinct color palettes for two different groups in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901720/distinct-color-palettes-for-two-different-groups-in-ggplot2) and [How to use multiple colormaps in seaborn on same plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25894800/how-to-use-multiple-colormaps-in-seaborn-on-same-plot).

For illustration, assume my dataframe as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':['G1','G1','G1','G2','G2','G2','G2','G2','G2','G2','G3','G3'],
              'item':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'k', 'L'],
             'result':[1,5,4,10,2,4,13,2,6,11,12,9],
             'desired palette (for example)': ['mako', 'mako', 'mako', 'rocket', 'rocket', 'rocket', 'rocket', 'rocket', 'rocket', 'rocket','crest', 'crest']})
```

```
    group   item    result  desired palette (for example)
0   G1  A   1   mako
1   G1  B   5   mako
2   G1  C   4   mako
3   G2  D   10  rocket
4   G2  E   2   rocket
5   G2  F   4   rocket
6   G2  G   13  rocket
7   G2  H   2   rocket
8   G2  I   6   rocket
9   G2  J   11  rocket
10  G3  k   12  crest
11  G3  L   9   cres
```

Therefore, within each group in `group` column, the items should be ranked (based on `result` column) and plot using different sequential color palettes. For example, for `G1`, I would like to set the palette to 'mako'; `G2`, 'rocket'; ...

`df.sort_values(by=['group','result'], inplace=True)`

`sns.barplot('item', 'result', hue='group',data=df, palette=["mako", "rocket", "crest"])`?

Can we plot them in one plot? How can we do this using seaborn?

I found a stupid solution:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 6))

ax.barh('item', 'result', data=df[df['group']=='G3'], color=sns.color_palette('Blues'), label="G3")
ax.barh('item', 'result', data=df[df['group']=='G2'], color=sns.color_palette('rocket_r'), label="G2")
ax.barh('item', 'result', data=df[df['group']=='G1'], color=sns.color_palette('mako_r'), label="G1")


ax.legend()
```

Desired fig:
[image]

But the colour for "G" is not right. Colours of G-J should be in sequence.

As comments from @JohanC:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 6))
for label, pal in zip(
sorted(df['group'].unique().tolist(), reverse=True),
['Blues','rocket_r','mako_r']):
    data = df[df['group']==label]
    ax.barh('item', 'result', data=data, color=sns.color_palette(pal, n_colors=len(data)), label=label)

plt.show()
```

The following code will only show the last one.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 6))
for label, pal in zip(
sorted(df['group'].unique().tolist(), reverse=True),
['Blues','rocket_r','mako_r']):
    sns.barplot(y='item', x='result', data=df[df['group']==label], color=sns.color_palette(pal))
```

Comment: You can do the same in Seaborn.  Why not?  (But in either case, it is recommended to write things in a loop, something like `for label, pal in zip(['G1','G2','G3'],['Blues','rocket_r','mako_r']): sns.barplot(data=df[df['group']==label], x='result', y='item', palette=pal, label=label)`

Comment: Section 3 of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68793513/7758804) of the duplicate.

Comment: @JohanC the loop might not work, it would show the last 'G3' plot only, will not overlay using seaborn?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thanks, I want all subplots combined into one big plot.

Comment: For the loop from @JohanC, you must put `plt.show()` inside the loop, after the plot call.

Comment: If you want a single figure, then follow the duplicate, as per my previous comment, unless that's what you were already confirming.

Comment: Thanks @TrentonMcKinney, `plt.show()` just show the subplots. Many apologies for the confusion, i added my desired fig in my question. Can seaborn achieve this? I used seaborn，only show the last one.